# Using JQuery Validation Plugin Remote Function - Help checking if email exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Im trying to use the remote feature in the JQuery Validation Plugin to check to see if the email address exists. I cannot get it to return the status of it being registered. I am using the default php class provided. I am using Jquery Latest

Here is my class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.setDefaults({
submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }});
$().ready(function() {

// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        user_pass: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        user_pass_confirm: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo: "#user_pass"
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: { url:"module/1.func.php",     
            type : "get",
            data : { email : function() { return $("#email").val();
 }, 
  }
  }        
        },

        terms: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        user_pass: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Password must be at least 6 characters"
        },
        user_pass_confirm: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Password must be at least 6 characters",
            equalTo: "Eenter the same password as above"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Enter your email address",
            email: "Enter a valid email address",


        },

        terms: "Please accept our policies"
    }
});

});
```

-----EDIT--ADDED 1.inc.php-----

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
if($email=="me@god.com"){
$valid = 'false';
}else{
$valid = 'true';
}
echo $valid;
?>
```

-----EDIT--Changed Jquery-----

I have now changed the email rule to the following. I get "Please Fix this field" when the email is inputted if it matches.

> email: {
>                 required: true,
>                 email: true,
>                 remote: "module/1.func.php"             },

Comment: Post the code in your `module/1.func.php`. You aren't giving us anything to work with.

Comment: Are you using this plugin? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your remote validator to

`remote: "module/1.func.php"`

It already sends the email via get and send that fields value.